# How to pip install a Python program such that it has a command line shortcut

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to write a Python program which I can `pip install` so that it has a certain command-line alias, similar to the 'aws' command with the `awscli` package (cf. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli/1.11.115).

The `setup.py` from the `awscli` seems to contain something like

```
setuptools.setup(console='bin/aws')
```

which is presumably what makes the command line 'alias' work. However, at http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html I was not able to easily find documentation or examples about how to use this `console` option.

My simplified use case is as follows. I have a directory `sayhello` which contains the following:

```
.
├── sayhello.py
└── setup.py
```

where `sayhello.py` has both a function (`say_hello`) defined and an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block to invoke this function:

```
def say_hello():
    print("Hello, world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    say_hello()
```

The `setup.py` I've tried is

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="sayhello", version="1.0", packages=find_packages(), console="/bin/sayhello")
```

Then in the `sayhello` directory, I do

```
pip install .
```

(after `virtualenv venv` and `source venv/bin/activate` to do it in a virtual environment). After this, I'm able to `import sayhello` and `sayhello.say_hello()` in a Python shell, for example, but the keyboard shortcut `sayhello` which I tried to define doesn't work.

How can I modify the `setup.py` such that the command `sayhello` triggers the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block in `sayhello.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe you need to put sayhello.py into a directory with an `__init__.py` for it to be found by `find_packages` (which is a requirement for the `entry_points` method). I am not sure about that (I have never tried it without), but I have been trying now and can't get it to work without that.

There are two ways I know of to create command line runnable scripts: [`entry_points`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) and [`scripts`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#basic-use).

`entry_points` is the more powerful option but requires the functionality of the script to be part of your package (meaning it resides in a module in your package. If you move `sayhello.py` into a `sayhello` directory with an `__init__.py` file, it would look like this:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'say_hello = sayhello.sayhello:say_hello'
    ]
}
```

The simpler option is `scripts`. Just add this:

```
scripts=['sayhello.py']
```

---

Here is what I have that is working:

`setup.py`

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(
    name="sayhello",
    version="1.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            "sayhello = sayhello.sayhello:say_hello"
        ]
    }
)
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── sayhello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sayhello.py
└── setup.py
```

`sayhello.py`

```
def say_hello():
    print("Hello, world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    say_hello()
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a `sayhello.py` in the root of your package. Then just add [`scripts`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) in your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['sayhello.py']
)
```

It's customary to put all scripts inside `scripts/` dir, make them executable, and put a hashbang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) in the first line.

The second approach is via [`console_scripts`](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point):

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['sayhello=sayhello:say_hello'],
    }
    ...
)
```

#### A minimal example

In `sayhello.py` put:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello!"
```

and in `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="sayhello",
    version="0.0.1",
    scripts=['sayhello.py']
)
```

After running `pip install .`, you should have your `sayhello.py` script copied to virtual environment's `bin` directory (which is in your `PATH`).

Test the script:

```
$ sayhello.py
Hello!
```

Comment: After the `pip install .`, in my virtual environment if I try to run the command `sayhello`, I get `-bash: sayhello: command not found`. How can I make this print "Hello, world"?

Comment: Try running `sayhello.py`. And put `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line.

Comment: In the same directory it works (as it would without the `pip install`), but if I go to a different directory I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'sayhello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: `pip install` should copy your script to virtualenv's `bin` directory (or symlink it). Check it's there. Also, your virtual environment has to be active.

Comment: @KurtPeek, check the minimal example I added to my answer.

Comment: [randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir), thanks, this works. (I accepted the other answer though because it is closer to a command-line shortcut like 'aws').

Comment: @KurtPeek, how do you mean closer to `aws`? Because it's inside a package, because of the extensions missing, or something else?

Comment: @KurtPeek, oh, and btw, no worries, accept the answer for which you feel best solves your problem.